# Has no exported member OpaqueToken

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic-framework, command-line-interface

Can anyone know about this error?

has no exported member OpaqueToken

Version:

Ionic Framework: ^3.9.9
Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.4
Angular Core: 5.2.9
Angular Compiler CLI: 8.2.14
Node: 10.16.3
OS Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0):

due to lack of information:

1. maybe you are not exporting the `OpaqueToken` in some of your ts files
2. maybe you are importing `OpaqueToken` twice (in your module and somes components).
3. `export default class Module {}` won't work also use `export class Module {}`
4. restart all services and web page and then `ng serve ...` or equivalent in ionic